# Imprimindo horarios com intervalos pré-determinados

Tags: php, array, time

estou tentando fazer um código que irá imprimir as horas em um determinado intervalo.

```
<?php 
//Array com os horarios que possam ser imprimidos
$hora = array('13:55:40','13:56:40','13:58:41','13:59:40','14:01:00','14:02:00','14:04:40',
'14:05:00','14:07:10','14:08:00','14:10:23', '14:11:23','14:13:39','14:14:23','14:16:39',
'14:17:23','14:19:13','14:20:23','14:22:40', '14:21:23','14:25:07', '14:26:23', '14:55:40');

//Intervalo que o usuario escolherá entre 3, 15, 30 ou 60
$interval = 15;

$base = explode(":", $hora[0]);
$horaBase = $base[0];
$minBase = $base[1];
$j = 1;

$tam = count($hora);
echo "Interval: {$interval} <br>";
echo "Tamanho do array: {$tam} <br>";
echo "<br>0: ".$hora[0]."<br>";

while($j < $tam){
    $time = explode(":", $hora[$j]);

    if($time[1] >= ($minBase+$interval)){
        echo $j." : ".$hora[$j]."<br>";
        $minBase += $interval;
    }
    if($horaBase < $hora[0]){
        $minBase -= 60;
        $horaBase = $hora[0];
    }
    $j++;
}?>
```

Por exemplo, usando um intervalo de 15 quero que os horários impressos sejam:

> 13:55:40, 14:10:23, 14:25:07

Mas esse código está imprimindo:

> 13:55:40, 13:58:41, 13:59:40, 14:55:40

Pra esse caso, o valor de base deve ser tomado como o primeiro valor do array.
Estou passando a lógica do código no papel e não consigo achar o problema..

Comment: Da forma que vc está tentando fazer não é possível obter sucesso. A solução passa pela `classe DateTime` . Um bom tutorial encontra-se em https://www.devmedia.com.br/manipulando-datas-com-php/32966

Comment: Caso alguma resposta solucionou seu problema não esqueça de marcá-la como aceita. Veja como e porque nesse post https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A criação de um objeto da classe `DateTime` é a maneira mais fácil de manipular datas na sua aplicação.
>
> Quando temos dois objetos da classe `DateTime` podemos compará-los com o método `diff()` que retorna um objeto `DateInterval` e que representa a diferença entre as duas datas, diferença essa que podemos retornar de acordo com o formato desejado utilizando a função `date_format ()`.
>
> <sup>Esses são os conceitos aplicados no script para se chegar ao resultado esperado. O código está bem comentado e não haverá dificuldades de localizar cada conceito acima aplicado ao código.</sup>

```
//Array com os horarios que possam ser imprimidos
$hora = array('13:55:40','13:56:40','13:58:41','13:59:40','14:01:00','14:02:00','14:04:40',
'14:05:00','14:07:10','14:08:00','14:10:23', '14:11:23','14:13:39','14:14:23','14:16:39',
'14:17:23','14:19:13','14:20:23','14:22:40', '14:21:23','14:25:07', '14:26:23', '14:55:40');

//Intervalo que o usuario escolherá entre 3, 15, 30 ou 60
$interval = 15;

//valor de base o primeiro valor do array.
$val1 = $hora[0];

print $val1;

for ($i=0;$i<(count($hora)-1);$i++) {

    $val2 = $hora[$i+1];

    //Instanciando objetos DateTime
    $datetime1 = new DateTime($val1);
    $datetime2 = new DateTime($val2);
    
    //Retorna a diferença entre dois objetos DateTime.
    $intervalo = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
    
    //Retorna a dìferença de acordo com um formato informado, neste caso minutos
    $result = $intervalo->format('%i');
    
    //imprime o valor cuja diferença é dada por $interval
    if($result == ($interval-1) || $result == ($interval)){
         print ", ".$val2;
         //atribui o valor encontrado $val2 em $val1 para buscar
         //próxima diferença $interval a partir deste
         $val1 = $val2;
    }

}
```

> OBS: Veja que a diferença entre 13:55:40, 14:10:23, é `14 minutos e 43 segundos` e não 15 minutos motivo pelo qual foi imposta a condição `if($result == ($interval-1) || $result == ($interval)){` , ou seja = 14 ou = 15

[**Ideone - $interval = 15**](https://ideone.com/Tp2gs8)

[**Ideone - $interval = 3**](https://ideone.com/GI8uX4)

**Outra forma de se obter o mesmo resultado, sem levar em conta os segundos é:**

```
//Array com os horarios que possam ser imprimidos
$hora = array('13:55:40','13:56:40','13:58:41','13:59:40','14:01:00','14:02:00','14:04:40',
'14:05:00','14:07:10','14:08:00','14:10:23','14:11:23','14:13:39','14:14:23','14:16:39',
'14:17:23','14:19:13','14:20:23','14:22:40', '14:21:23','14:25:07', '14:26:23', '14:55:40');

//Intervalo que o usuario escolherį entre 3, 15, 30 ou 60
$interval = 3;

$val1 = $hora[0];

print $val1;

//formata para am/pm sem segundos
$val1P = date( 'g:i a', strtotime($val1) );

for ($i=0;$i<(count($hora)-1);$i++) {

    $val2 = $hora[$i+1];

    //formata para am/pm sem segundos
    $val2P = date( 'g:i a', strtotime($val2) );
    
    $datetime1 = new DateTime($val1P);
    $datetime2 = new DateTime($val2P);
    
    $intervalo = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
    
    $result = $intervalo->format('%i');

    if($result == $interval){

         print ", ".$val2;
         $val1P = $val2P;

    }

}
```

[**Ideone - $interval = 3**](https://ideone.com/vNHPsA)

Answer (score 0):

Da maneira a qual você tentou seria possivel, porém seriá uma má pratica! Nesse seu caso o ideal seria usar a função nativa do PHP `strtotime`,e dentro da função passar como parâmetro hora atual e o tempo que deseja acrescentar a hora atual, nesse caso passamos a hora e os minutos que deseja somar, isso irá retornar um `timestamp`, converteremos esse `timestamp` a uma hora legível, isso com auxilio da função `date` também nativa do PHP, onde receberá como parâmetros o retorno esperado e o `timestamp` que deseja converter.

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/Sao_Paulo");

//Use a variável abaixo para definir uma hora inicial
//$horaDefinida = '10:10';

//Use a variável abaixo para pegar a hora automaticamente
$horaDefinida = date('H:i');
$tempoEmMinutos = 15;
$quantidadeIntervalos = 10;


$interval = 0;
while($interval <= $quantidadeIntervalos){

    $horaNova = strtotime("$horaDefinida + ".$tempoEmMinutos." minutes");
    $horaNovaFormatada = date("H:i:s",$horaNova);   
    $horaDefinida = $horaNovaFormatada;

    echo $horaNovaFormatada;
    echo "<br>";

    $interval++;

}


//Hora com acrescimos a partir de um array

$horas = array('13:55:40','13:56:40','13:58:41','13:59:40','14:01:00','14:02:00','14:04:40',
'14:05:00','14:07:10','14:08:00','14:10:23', '14:11:23','14:13:39','14:14:23','14:16:39',
'14:17:23','14:19:13','14:20:23','14:22:40', '14:21:23','14:25:07', '14:26:23', '14:55:40');


foreach ($horas as $hora) {

    $horaNova = strtotime("$hora + ".$tempoEmMinutos." minutes");
    $horaNovaFormatada = date("H:i:s",$horaNova);

    echo 'Hora antiga:'.$hora.' Hora nova: '.$horaNovaFormatada.'<br>';

}
```

> Note que a função 'date_default_timezone_set' foi adicionada para setar um local padrão, para que a hora seja correta
>
> Leia mais sobre as funções 'date' e 'strtotime'

Comment: Creio eu, que isso não responde a questão dele , porque ele queria exibir os valores num intervalo , pq ele n quer acrescentar a hora mas sim localizar as que batem com o intervalo

Comment: @ViniciusShiguemori tem razão! Minha resposta foi com base o começo da pergunta "estou tentando fazer um código que irá imprimir as horas em um determinado intervalo."

Comment: Vou editar o código!

Comment: blz, tava elaborando o codigo tbm, mas o seu modo está bem mais elaborado que o meu, aguardando para ver como vai ficar

Answer (score 0):

Veja se ajuda:

```
$start = new \DateTime('08:00');
$times = 12 * 2; // 24 hours * 30 mins in an hour
$result[0] = $start->format('H:i');
for ($i = 0; $i < $times - 1; $i++) {
    $result[] = $start->add(new \DateInterval('PT30M'))->format('H:i');
}
```

Comment: Poderia colocar uma breve explicação da sua resposta?

Comment: Claro. Utilizei ele num projeto. Gera um array de horários numa janela de 24h onde ele acrescenta 30min (no DateInterval) em cada hora e já inicia o array com o horário que você definir no $start.